# Insert text before existing textbox content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a short jQuery script that adds text like `images:` into a search box when a user clicks a link. However, if the user clicks a different tab instead the search they have typed is deleted. I want to keep what the user has typed *(if they have typed anything)* which will **always** be after the `:`. **Anything before it can be deleted.**

How do I do this?

My current jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navigation a").click(function(){
        $("#search").val($(this).attr("id")+': ').focus();
        return false
    });
});
```

My HTML is:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#" id="images">Images</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="videos">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="articles">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="weather">Weather</a></li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="search">
```

You can see a working example of the current code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zusnw/

Comment: What if the user type something followed by `:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$("#navigation a").click(function(){
    var search = $('#search'),
        curVal = $('#search').val(),
        i = curVal.indexOf(':'),
        newVal = i !== -1 ? curVal.substring(i) : ': ' + curVal;
    $('#search').focus().val(this.id + newVal);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Zusnw/8/).

Comment: Because `val()` returns a string, which has no `focus()` method. Hence the clarification that I hadn't tested, that was just my first-thoughts. The updated answer works.

Comment: Why wouldn't there be a `:` in the value, since the script explicitly adds one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navigation a").click(function(){
        var searchBox = $("#search");
        var searchBoxVal = searchBox.val();     
        var newVal = '';
        if(searchBoxVal.indexOf(":") > -1)
        {
            // get the content after the colon...
            newVal = this.id + ":" +searchBoxVal.substring(searchBoxVal.indexOf(":")+1);
        }
        else
        {
            newVal = this.id + ": ";
            if(searchBoxVal.length > 0) 
            {
                // if colon not found but user has type anythings...
                newVal += searchBoxVal;
            }
        }
        searchBox.val(newVal);
        searchBox.focus();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Modified the code to handle no colon case. If there is no `:`, we would use the content that users have modified.